# How to use skewer mode beyond localhost?

Tags: networking, http, skewer-mode

I'd like to write the code for a website on one pc and see the results in a browser on another pc in my local network.

For calling the skewer script in html, I replaced localhost with the local ip of pc1 – `<script src="*pc1.ip*:8080/skewer"></script>`.

But simple-httpd seems to only serve the site (and skewer script) on localhost, when I try to access `*pc1.ip*:8080` via pc2 I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

Other simple http serve solutions (i.e. `python -m http.server 8080`) are accessable via local network, however they don't "interact" with skewer.

Is there a way to access simple-httpd via non-localhost? Or maybe a way to connect skewer and another serving solution?

/EDIT1 - after DoMiNeLa10♦'s comment/
Tried to set `httpd-host` to `pc1.ip` – now I can access the page via pc2 – but no skewer functionality (no autorefresh on save, no `skewer-eval-*`,…).

/EDIT2 - again thanks to DoMiNeLa10♦'s comment/
Tried adding a domain name for pc1 ("pc1" ^^) in `/etc/hosts` on both pc 
and changed to `<script src="http://pc1:8080/skewer"></script>` in html.
No luck –> `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` on pc2

Comment: This seems to be related to the variable `httpd-host`, which is passed to `make-network-process`, which compares its value against the host that's requested. You can try commenting out the line that provides it to that function in `httpd-start`. That might be your culprit, and the whole issue might be worth reporting, as such a feature can be quite useful.

Comment: Thanks for hint! Tried to set `httpd-host` to `pc1.ip` – now I can access the page via pc2 – but no "skewer functionality" on both pc…

Comment: As a quick hack you can add entries with the same domain name in `/etc/hosts` on both machines. Just make sure the IP address points to the right machine in both cases, they will end up being different.

Comment: Like so: `/etc/hosts` on pc1 add line `127.0.0.1 pc1` – `/etc/hosts` on pc2 add line `192.168.2.100 pc1` – set `httpd-host` to `pc1` and `<script src="pc1:8080/skewer"></script>`?
 (`ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` when I try to access pc1:8080 via pc2 – no skewer functionality on pc1…)

Comment: Try adding the protocol (`http://`) before the link, I have a feeling browsers are picky about URLs like this if you don't give them the protocol explicitly.

Comment: It's not that – chromium seems to "assume" http anyway. (Of cource I tried nevertheless – no difference)

Comment: …I have to correct my  "no skewer functionality on pc1"-comment before. It works when html is changed accordingly – still no luck via pc2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to setting `httpd-host` to a hostname is to set it to an IP.  You can use `0.0.0.0` to bind to all local IP addresses.  Try `(setq httpd-host "0.0.0.0")` (it works for me).

Comment: Yey - that works. 
Just adding: in html skewer must still be loaded via `<script src="http://pc1:8888/skewer"></script>`

Comment: …and even without hosts entry at all and just the IP – meaning skewer can be used in different local networks with zero configuration needed on viewers side. Could become very handy =)